# How to access the type of an attribute in a TypedDict?

Tags: python, python-typing, typeddict

Given a `TypedDict`, how can you access/use the type of one of its attributes?

For example:

```py
class Shape(TypedDict):
  kind: Literal['square', 'circle']
  x: int
  y: int

KindOfShape: TypeAlias = Shape.kind # does not work - how do I do this?

kind_1: KindOfShape = 'circle'
kind_2: KindOfShape = 'spongebob' # I want this to error
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Why not create the TypeAlias first and use that as the annotation for the `kind` attribute/field? `KindOfShape: TypeAlias = Literal['square', 'circle']` - `kind: KindOfShape`

Comment: Try `TypeAlias = Shape.__annotations__['kind']` to access the type of `kind`.

Comment: In my case, there are a large number of attributes; giving each their own named type would make the code less readable.

Comment: @martineau I don't think that works, unfortunately – the type is only available at runtime, not statically, at least with pyright.

Comment: It's only avaiable after the class has been defined.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this possible?

**No.** There are 2 syntactic errors that can be summed up in 1 single sentence of PEP 589:

> [PEP 589 – TypedDict: Type Hints for Dictionaries with a Fixed Set of Keys](https://peps.python.org/pep-0589/)
>
> [Class-based Syntax]
>
> 1. **Methods are not allowed**, since
> 2. **the runtime type of a TypedDict object will always be just dict** (it is never a subclass of dict).

1. The first syntax impossibility in the example is:

   ```py
    Shape.kind # does not work - how do I do this?
   ```

   You don't. That's using attribute access `X.Y`, but PEP 589 is clear that the `TypedDict` is a dictionary, so you'll have to use key-value dictionary access using `Shape['kind']` syntax
2. The `TypedDict` type hint is strict in its syntax and **doesn't allow adding any methods** on the declaration (or metaclass) so there's no Data Model hack that would allow using dotted attribute access syntax.

   So the right way to do this would be as follows:

   ```py
   from typing import TypedDict, Literal, TypeAlias


   KindOfShape: TypeAlias = Literal['square', 'circle']


   class Shape(TypedDict):
       kind: KindOfShape
       x: int
       y: int


   kind_1: KindOfShape = 'circle'
   kind_2: KindOfShape = 'spongebob' # I want this to error
   ```

   Mypy gives the exact error you want:

   ```
   your module.py:14: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Literal['spongebob']", variable has type "Union[Literal['square'], Literal['circle']]")
   Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
   ```

An argument can be made:

> In my case, there are a large number of attributes; giving each their own named type would make the code less readable.

Not necessarily, you can (and often should) throw all the type hints into a stub file. It's meant to separate the static part from the run-time part. Granted, you have the extra work of writing the type hints but the whole point of using `TypeAlias` is code reuse, so you'll get the extra work back from writing separate definitions.